# How to get confirmation of Google Group address

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I stumbled across a Gmail Group guide from a couple of years ago. Basically I followed its steps and created a group with the `name@googlegroups.com` format. I logged into my original address and went to `Settings > Forward and POP/IMAP, added the Google Group address and it says it sends a confirmation message. The thing is, where does this message go to? It doesn't show up on the original address inbox nor does it show up in the group itself.

Comment: Did you sign up as a member of the Google Group? It won't send a message to a non-member. Does the group actually send email? This won't work for a "web-only" group.

Answer (score 1):

You have add the users in order to send confirmation mail.Follow the steps below to add users and send confirmation email.

> - From the Topics screen, click on the Manage button. A list of items    appears on the left-hand side of the screen.
> - Click on Members. Several items are listed.
> - Click on Directly add members. The Add/Invite members screen appears.
> - Click the Add members directly tab. The Add members directly panel is    displayed.
> - Type the email addresses of the people to add, separated by commas,    in the ‘Enter email address to add as members’ field.
> - In order to directly add members, you're required to type a welcome    message, which you can type in the “Write a welcome message” field.
> - Click on one of the options under “Email subscription options” to set    how users will use email to interact with the group.
> - Click the Add button to directly add the people to your group.

From: [Google Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2465460?hl=en)

Comment: Please cite your sources when you use text verbatim and place blockquotes around the quoted portion.